# Dispaly data from getOutputBuffers to ANativeWindow

Tags: android-ndk, android-mediacodec, nativewindow

Im trying to display the decoded data manually to a native window. But I cant seem to display it. I dont have any idea. Our project will be ndk and more native codes.

Your thoughts are very much appreciated.

```
uint8_t* decoded = AMediaCodec_getOutputBuffer(d->codec, status, out);
err = ANativeWindow_lock(mWindow, &buffer, NULL);
if(err == 0) {
   memcpy(buffer->bits, decoded, sizeof(decoded));
   ANativeWindow_unlockAndPost(mWindow);
}
```

Comment: what is the issue? do you have any error?

Comment: @E.Abdel there are no errors :(